# Characteristic coordinates $ξ(x, y)$ and $η(x, y)$ for $xu_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$ when $x<0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, linear-pde

How would I determine the characteristic coordinates for  $xu_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$?

This PDE reads $au_{xx} + 2b u_{xy} + cu_{yy} = 0$ with $a=x, b=0, c=1$. The polynomial equation $a\lambda^2 -2b\lambda +c =0 $
implies $\lambda^2 =  \frac{-1}{x}$.
Since $x<0$, we can take $x=-a$ where $a>0$ and so we get $\lambda^2 =  \frac{1}{a}$ and thus $\lambda = dy/dx=  \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$
Solving this would give me 
$y = \mp 2\sqrt{a} + c = \mp2\sqrt{-x} +c$, 
and so $c = y \pm 2\sqrt{-x}$.
Finally, $$ξ(x, y) = y+2\sqrt{-x} \qquad\text{and}\qquad η(x, y) = y-2\sqrt{-x}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Further reading: p. 161-162 of R. Courant, D. Hilbert (1962) *Methods of Mathematical Physics* vol. II: "Partial differential equations", Wiley-VCH. [doi:10.1002/9783527617234](https://dx.doi.org/10.1002/9783527617234)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it out, set $u(x,y)=v(ξ,η)=v(y+2\sqrt{−x},y-2\sqrt{−x})$ so that
\begin{align}
u_x&=-\frac1{\sqrt{-x}}(v_ξ-v_η),& u_y&=v_ξ+v_η\\
u_{xx}&=\frac1{-x}(v_{ξξ}-2v_{ξη}+v_{ηη})+\frac1{2x\sqrt{-x}}(v_ξ-v_η),& u_{yy}&=v_{ξξ}+2v_{ξη}+v_{ηη}
\end{align}
so that
$$
xu_{xx}+u_{yy}=4v_{ξη}+\frac1{2\sqrt{-x}}(v_ξ-v_η)
$$
which is likely what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Cheers mate, just wanted to confirm